# Can I have more than one db_recovery_file_dest?

Tags: oracle, recovery

Can I use more than one db_recovery_file_dest? I have several partitions which could be used, but I think it is not possible to have more than one db_recovery_file_dest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have only one *Flash Recovery Area* defined by the `db_recovery_file_dest`. If you do not want to use one directory then you can go for `ASM` where you can create and use a disk group that can span multiple disks/partitions.

You can also go for `LVM` if you use Linux. This is simular to `ASM`. Create a physical group that contains multiple partitions. On that physical group you create a logical volume and mount it to a directory.